# Azure Kubernetes Service, Access repository (A) from another repository (B)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-registry

Suppose we have repositories (A, B) in the same container registry.

I need to have repo (A) as a dependency inside rep (B). Or I should be able to access repo A.

From repository (B), I need to access multiple functionality of repository(A). Both are python3 application repos. created by two different pipelines and docker files.

I'm a newbie on AZURE.